# Is there a children command to complement the parents command?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

Mercurial provides the command parents to examine a given revision's parent(s).  This can easily be used to Traverse the DAG backward.  I need to traverse the DAG forward.  Is there a `hg children` command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using Mercurial 1.6 or later, there is a built-in functional language for specifying sets of revisions; see `hg help revsets` for full details.

In your case, you would use

```
hg log -r "children(XXX)"
```

to show immediate children of revision `XXX`, or

```
hg log -r "descendants(XXX)"
```

to show all changesets with `XXX` as an ancestor.

Answer (score 2):

Use the bundled [`children` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChildrenExtension). `hg help children` (1.5):

```
hg children [-r REV] [FILE]

show the children of the given or working directory revision

    Print the children of the working directory's revisions. If a revision is
    given via -r/--rev, the children of that revision will be printed. If a
    file argument is given, revision in which the file was last changed (after
    the working directory revision or the argument to --rev if given) is
    printed.

options:

 -r --rev       show children of the specified revision
    --style     display using template map file
    --template  display with template
```